# Sockets: sometimes (rarely) packets are lost during receiving

Tags: c#, udp

I'm using `Socket` to receive data from udp multicast.
The code is trivial:

```
s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
....
while (true)
{
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        count = socket.Receive(byteArray);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return;
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        OnNewMessage(new NewMessageEventArgs(byteArray, count));
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I lose packets. Not too often, ~ once per 2 minutes.

I'm sure that packet is arrived because I can see it in another C++ program launched on the same computer and configured to receive same packets.

Why my program can not catch packets that others can? Why I lose packets? Is it possible that computer is just too slow (or too busy) to receive packets?

I receive about 2 000 packets per second and using Xeon E3 processor, that should be more that enough I think...

Comment: Maybe its because UDP is not reliable. You will loose packets and possible you don't get a message at all.

Comment: @dowhilefor I wrote that message is not lost! because I do see it on the same machine in another program. So message IS delivired to network card driver. Moreover my program constantly lose message when another program do not! So problem not with UDP, problem with a program.

Comment: @javapowered - Yes, Yes it is.

Comment: Your exit condition here should be count <= 0

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry I don't understand. Socket.Receive returns "The number of bytes received." I process packet if more than 0 bytes received. Is that wrong?

Comment: [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx) "the Receive method will block until data is available" (unless you are using timeouts), so the only time I would expect <=0 is if the socket is closed. Any other time, the result should be a positive number of bytes.

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't care about exit condition. I need to receive data always. If there are no data it would be very very bad because this is stock exchange information that I need for trading :)

Comment: @javapowered I didn't say "no data" - that is completely different. If there is "no data", then **as documented** it will block until there **is** some data. I said "socket it closed". If the socket is closed, no more data is ***ever*** coming in. That is an exit condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure the packet is arriving (and: I must emphasise that this is **not** guaranteed when using UDP, and 1 packet dropped every two mintes at 2000 packets a second is a better receive rate than you should probably hope for, even for two adjacent machines), then this *possibly* means that the receive buffer is full at brief moments. Try increasing the [`ReceiveBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Marc, yes I'm absolutely sure that packet actually arrived because I do see it in Wireshark etc. Moreover when starting application after receiveing first ~100 packets I constantly loose next ~1000 packets! I will try to increase this buffer right away!

Answer (score 0):

I don't no if is your case, but sometimes your can receive more the one packets in a single byte array of socket.Receive(byteArray). It is due to an optimization of sockets. 
Check if it's your case, and check your parsing methods.

Comment: what you saying is against msdn "If you are using a connectionless Socket, Receive will read the first enqueued datagram from the destination address you specify in the Connect method."

Comment: Ok you're right, I just read msdn bible.. I have this problem in a TCP connection and I thought that I was a problem of the receive method.