# should I use while(true) to receive data from Socket?

Tags: c#, sockets

Please refer my previous question for code sample [Sockets: sometimes (rarely) packets are lost during receiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826194/sockets-sometimes-rarely-packets-are-lost-during-receiving)

I need to receive data always from UDP multicast socket. This is one-way comminication I just need to listen for new data and process it asap.

Should I use `while(true)`? I don't like `while(true)` because in my opinion this produce a lot of extra-work for processor. Probably c# offers other call-back techniques or something?

Comment: What specific call are you using to listen for new packets? there are lots of ways that can be done, and it matters. Also: what is the nature of the application? How many broadcasts is it listening too? if just this one (or a few), then a dedicated thread and blocking read calls is probably not a problem. For a dedicated server with dozens or hundreds or thousands of connections, you'll definitely want to use callback IO or Socket.Select.

Comment: @MarcGravell I should listen for several sockets (from 2 to 6), i'm using dedicated thread for each Socket. I receive ~2000 packets per second on each socket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 to 6 sockets (comments) is probably in the interesting place where either blocking or async IO will work fine, since you aren't swamping the machine with threads. With 2000 packets per second, it sounds like there is plenty to keep the threads busy. You don't need to worry about `while(true)` from a *performance* perspective, since the `Receive` method will block until data is available, so it is **never** doing a hot-loop of doing nothing. However! Personally, from a cosmetic perspective, I agree `while(true)` is an unnecessary blot, so if you are using the blocking approach, maybe consider:

```
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = socket.Receive(buffer)) > 0) {
    // process bytesRead from buffer
}
```

which will exit cleanly when the socket is closed.

You *can also* do this with either the `BeginReceive` and `Socket.ReceiveAsync` methods, which doesn't use a blocking call, but instead uses either an event or callback. These are particularly useful when handling lots of connections.

*Personally*, what I tend to do is use `Socket.Available`; if this is positive, then there is data buffered and ready to consume, so a simple `Receive` can be used to fetch that data promptly and without a context-switch. If it is zero, then no data is **currently** available, so an async call may be more appropriate. This balances context-switches with direct calls. Note that the `ReceiveAsync` approach has this built in too, via the return value from `ReceiveAsync` (which is `true` if the operation is incomplete, and a callback will be invoked later - and `false` if the operation is **already** complete, and **no** callback will be invoked).

Comment: thank you Marc. I assume that my task (receive multicast data from several UDP socket) is so much general that there should be "ideal" solution. This is what people need to do to watch ip tv or radio and to receive data from "stock exchange" in my case. I'm sure "recomended to use" code sample should be somewhere probably even somewhere in msdn. Probably someone can link such code sample...

Comment: Also probably you know why I lose pacekts :( see my linked question

Comment: @javapowered er yes... **because you are using UDP**. That is normal.

Comment: Marc, no no no. Another application on the same computer RECEIVE packets. This is not about UDP. If packet IS delivered using UDP then I assume ALL applications on the host MUST receive it. It is not normal that I can see packet from one application but can not see it from another application.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for sockets programming is using their Async counterparts. Instead of running endless loops you should call BeginReceive and set it's callback method which will fire upon completion of the transmission. That way you'll retain control over your app and use much less resources.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx#Y0

Comment: Have nothing to object to that. Will be more precise in my answers from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Async method is the best solution.

However in this case if you use while(true) that contains socket.Receive(buf) there's no extra work for processor because if you don't set a timeout the sockect block the loop until data arrives.