# VB.NET socket support has limit on size of incoming data?

Tags: vb.net, windows, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a command language that serves requests on a TCP socket server on a Linux-based box. The language is simple line-oriented text so that humans can play with it, but the expectation is that most queries will be automated.

One query in particular results in about 600kB of (text) data being sent back in one burst. All the Linux or OS X clients I've tested handle this just fine. However, I have a customer who develops in VB.NET/Windows whose application is having trouble accepting that amount of data at once. Every time his app issues this query, it captures the first 78,822 bytes of returned data, but then loses the rest. He has tried many different approaches to raise the limit, none had any effect. That 78,822 number seems to be pretty consistent, although we can't figure out why (e.g. it isn't anything good-looking in hex).

As a test, I tried connecting by hand on a Win7 using the [Microsoft telnet client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx), as well as [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), and both also failed to handle all the incoming data. Although I'm not familiar with Microsoft tools, this really surprised me; TCP clients should be able to handle many megabytes of data.

Here's the code he's using (posted with permission):

```
Dim mySocket As Socket = Nothing

' Create a TCP/IP socket.
mySocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
mySocket.SendTimeout = 5000
mySocket.ReceiveTimeout = 10000
mySocket.Blocking = True

mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize = 8192

Dim intBytesRead As Integer = 0
Dim intTotBytes As Int32 = 0

Do While mySocket.Available > 0

    Try
        intBytesRead = mySocket.Receive(bytesReceived, intTotBytes, 8192, SocketFlags.None)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        intTotBytes += intBytesRead
    Catch exSocket As SocketException
        If exSocket.ErrorCode = SocketError.WouldBlock OrElse _
            exSocket.ErrorCode = SocketError.IOPending OrElse _
            exSocket.ErrorCode = SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable Then
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        ElseIf exSocket.ErrorCode = SocketError.TimedOut Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Throw exSocket
        End If
    Finally
    End Try
Loop
```

(Edit: I forgot to mention that in the problematic scenario, the code generally exits when the socket throws a `SocketError.TimedOut` exception.)

As a workaround I've rewritten my language to allow fetching only 60kB of data at a time, and he's now up and running with that, but I'm still a bit concerned by the limit.

Any ideas why this code, or VB.NET socket code in general, wouldn't be able to handle a large burst of incoming data?

Comment: You can't control, on any system (regardless of OS and/or language), how much data is received over a TCP connection.  TCP is an endless stream of bytes and **has no notion of how big your "message" is**.  Your data may, or may **not**, be received in one "chunk".  TCP only guarantees it will all arrive in the correct **order**.  It would be perfectly normal for some of the bytes to be received, then more later.  TCP will **not** know that more data is on the way.  Using `mySocket.Available > 0` doesn't do squat to ensure you've "received all the data".

Comment: `Socket.Available` only tells you that **currently** there is data in the buffer waiting to be read (it has already been received, but hasn't been read by you).  Since TCP has no idea how big your "message" is, though, this doesn't indicate whether more data is on the way, or whether all of your data has been received.  It's up to you to develop a **protocol** for knowing when all data has been received.  Somehow tell the recipient how many bytes to expect, or somehow delimit the "end of a message", or both.

Comment: Good point, @Idle_Mind, and I'll mention it to him. However, at one point that `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)` was actually `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`, which didn't change the data received. It doesn't seem likely that TCP and the Windows network stack would take over a second to pass on the data.

Comment: (BTW, my language does have a clear protocol for "that's all the data you're getting", but he isn't using it, and you're right: that's an issue.)

Comment: On the flip side, you can have the opposite problem occur.  If you sent two separate "messages", they can get bunched together and be received in one "chunk" (but still in the correct order byte wise).  The protocol will allow the receiver to know that more than one message is contained within.

Comment: Long story, short, your developer needs to change `Do While mySocket.Available > 0` to something that correctly loops (or takes action somehow) when all the data has been received based on your protocol, not based on the `Available()` method.

Comment: I just added a note to my question: when the code breaks before receiving all the data, it exits with a `SocketError.TimedOut` exception. So, although `Socket.Available` isn't the right tool to decide when the incoming data is done, that isn't what's going on in this situation.

Comment: How do you send the data? I mean, if you're even able to crash telnet, there may be something in _your_ code that's causing the issue. VB.NET just uses Winsock2 internally. Do the `WouldBlock`, `IOPending` or `NoBufferSpaceAvailable` exceptions occur? The socket is blocking anyway, so don't use `Socket.Available`, [use a busy loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835179/should-i-use-whiletrue-to-receive-data-from-socket).

Comment: When using WinTelnet or PuTTY, the response is displayed up to a certain point, and then the rest of the data is lost. After that, the socket seems to die on the Windows end; the server finds its end closed and shuts down that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles onto this, I'll report the answer: it was my own (Linux-based) code. The client was slower at processing the received than I'd experienced in testing, which meant that my output buffers filled up and some of my writes were failing with an EAGAIN error. Unfortunately I wasn't handling that error, so my writes failed and the socket was closed.

Mea culpa.